# Declare WKWebView delegates in a macOS 10.8+ compatible app

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, wkwebview

Let me be more clear. I have an app which is macOS 10.8+ compatible, however I want to use `WKWebView` if the user is using macOS 10.10+, to give him/her a better experience.

I created a `NSView`-based class which should automatically add a `WebView` if the user is using macOS 10.9 or below, and `WKWebView` if it's using 10.10 or superior. The problem comes when I need to declare `WKWebView` navigation and UI delegates.

I can add the WebView delegate functions without any trouble:

```
-(WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;

-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation 
       request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame 
                            decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener;
```

However, I need to declare the functions below to able to control the WKWebView flow as well:

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration 
   forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
        windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures;

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```

However, both use, together, `WKWebView`, `WKWebViewConfiguration`, `WKNavigationAction`, `WKWindowFeatures` and `WKNavigationActionPolicy`, which were not available in macOS 10.9 and below.

Based in my experience with `NSUserNotificationCenter`, I know that if I declare a function with those objects, it app will immediately crash on launch in macOS 10.8 and 10.9 because those classes aren't available. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem. Selectors in Objective-C do not consider type, so I declared the WKWebView needed functions with more primitive classes which are inherited by the original ones:

```
- (id)webView:(id)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(id)configuration 
                                     forNavigationAction:(id)navigationAction 
                                          windowFeatures:(id)windowFeatures; 

- (void)webView:(id)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(id)navigationAction 
                                            decisionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger))decisionHandler;
```

Since I can't add the protocols to the view class (since they don't exist in macOS 10.9- as well) I receive some warnings, but that's a different issue. The code above works, and is compatible with macOS 10.8 and 10.9, like I desired.